# android - no default constructor in view

Tags: android

I have a problem with using a class that extends android.view.View, which is odd because I am doing the same thing in two different projects, and only in one of them is this an issue.

Both projects have a class which says: `public class ClassName extends View`.

But for one of them, this line is underlined red, and the message given is

> "There is no default constructor available in 'android.view.View' "

I do not know why one has this problem while the other does not. They are not the same classes, naturally, but they both extend View in the same way. I thought that this would be a common problem but I'm not finding anything about it through Google searching, so I  am asking here. Thank you for any help you can give!

EDIT:

The comments made me check again, and sure enough, the class with the error did not have a constructor defined in its class. I find it interesting that even though I went and defined a constructor, it still gave the same error until I added parameters (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) and in the constructor added a line 'super(context, attrs)'. I added these because they were present in the working class's constructor. So the working version is

```
public DrawingActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
}
```

My new question is about what exactly this does. This was taken from the class that didn't have the error, and that version was originally copied from a tutorial and never gave it much thought at the time.

Comment: Look into the other class. You will find one or more constructors.

Comment: do you have an empty constructor ( a constructor without parameters) in your view?

Comment: post your `ClassName` class.

Comment: post code of your class

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 6):

Delete construct without params.

Your view should have only 3 constructors:

```
public DrawingActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public DrawingActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}
public DrawingActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

About this constructors you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). I can mention only about defStyle:

> The default style to apply to this view. If 0, no style will
>   be applied (beyond what is included in the theme). This may either be
>   an attribute resource, whose value will be retrieved from the current
>   theme, or an explicit style resource.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is his problem ...
This does not work:

```
`public MyPanel(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    super(context);`
```

This does work:

```
`public MyPanel(Context _context) {
    super(_context);
    context = _context;`
```

I'm guessing this was his problem, or at least it was my problem. You get the same error that he describes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two constructors in your class:

```
public class ABC extends View{   

public ABC(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ABC(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}}
```